# Python incrementing IP range in for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to increment the start_ip and end_ip each iteration by 1. Although whenever the function results in the else statement 'already active' the counter keeps going. Is there a way to make number1 pause in the for loop when it hits ip is active? I tried decrementing it by one and adding a break but that does not seem to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
        
import requests
import time
import re
        
headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8','User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate','Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'}
        
def log(ip):  
              log = open("ip_active.txt","a+")
              log.write(ip)
              log.close
    
     
def start_ip():
       x = 0
       while x == 0:
         for number1 in range(1,254):
          
           start_ip = '192.168.' + str(number1) + '.1'
           end_ip = '192.168.' + str(number1) +'.254'
           
           with open('ip_list.txt', 'r') as iplist:
            for ip in iplist:      
               with open('ip_active.txt', 'r') as ipactive:
                try:
                   if(ip not in ipactive):   
                     log(ip)
                     print('Running task: ' + ip +f'task.exe%20{start_ip}%20{end_ip}')
                     target = ip.strip()+f'task.exe%20{start_ip}%20{end_ip}'
                     r = requests.get(target, allow_redirects=True, verify=False, headers=headers, timeout=1)
                     
                   else:
                     #Here number1 keeps incrementing as well but should not.
                     print(f'ip {ip} already active')  
                     time.sleep(2)
                    
                                  
                except:
                   print('Timeout')
                   continue    
              
def main():
       start_ip()
    
      
if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Output:

`ip http ://172.16.86.153 already active ip http ://172.16.86.152 already active Running task: http://172.16.86.153/?747fb083889d4d3591b8e185032f958c= task.exe%20192.168.**1**.1%20192.168.**1**.254 Running task: http://172.16.86.152/?93440f9cf9f743f2b5e4269ec73d4b78= task.exe%20192.168.**2**.1%20192.168.**2**.254 ip http ://172.16.86.153 already active ip http ://172.16.86.152 already active`

It should continue with:

`Running task: http ://172.16.86.152/?93440f9cf9f743f2b5e4269ec73d4b78= task.exe%20192.168.**3**.1%20192.168.**3**.254 Running task: http ://172.16.86.153/?93440f9cf9f743f2b5e4269ec73d4b78= task.exe%20192.168.**4**.1%20192.168.**4**.254`

but now it results in for example :

`Running task: http ://172.16.86.152/?93440f9cf9f743f2b5e4269ec73d4b78= task.exe%20192.168.**120**.1%20192.168.**120**.254 Running task: http ://172.16.86.153/?93440f9cf9f743f2b5e4269ec73d4b78= task.exe%20192.168.**121**.1%20192.168.**121**.254`

As can be seen when an IP is available it is running the task for example with IP 192.168.12.1 192.168.12.254, for the next IP: 192.168.13.1 192.168.13.254, next ip 192.168.14.1 192.168.14.254 and so on. However when an IP is already active it keeps counting, so it skips those for Running tasks.

Comment: what does `if(start_ip)` do? `start_ip` is a function name right

Comment: You should never modify the loop variable. It just gets reset each time. What is the purpose of `counter`? You never change it

Comment: Can you edit the question to give a minimal working example of the problem, and showing the expected outcome.

Comment: By the way, you're skipping a lot of addresses, such as `192.186.1.200`... Also, `192.168.1.199task.exe%20192.168.1.199%20192.168.1.254` doesn't seem like a valid HTTP address

Comment: file1.txt keeps a list of IPs and in ip_active.txt I put the ips that are currently running a task. Once it is completed it is removed from the active list so it is provided a new ip through the loop. if(start_ip) checks if there is an IP available by comparing the 2 files.

Counter isnt doing anything, it just keeps the while loop going.

Comment: Please as @defladamouse writes, give examples of file1.txt and ip_active.txt as well as what you expect to see as an output, otherwise it might be a bit harder to get help.